# Firestore error message: Operator string 'in' is invalid

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm executing this query on firebase firestore using python:

```
groups = ['AG', 'PA']

docs = db.collection(u'companies').document(company).collection('counts').\
document(count_name).collection('preprocess').\
where('status', '==', 'done').where('statuslayers', '==', 'done').\
where('statuslive', '==', 'created').\
where('load', '==', False).where('group', 'in', groups).\
order_by(u'area').stream()

for doc in docs:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

This error is triggered:

*Operator string 'in' is invalid. Valid choices are: <, <=, ==, >, >=, array_contains.*

The sample on [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) page is very near:

```
cities_ref = db.collection(u'cities')

query = cities_ref.where(u'country', u'in', [u'USA', u'Japan'])
return query
```

I couldn't find any reason to this error, if I remove the ***where('group', 'in', groups)*** clause everything works fine.

My google related packages:

- google-api-core 1.15.0
- google-api-python-client 1.7.11
- google-auth 1.10.0
- google-auth-httplib2               0.0.3
- google-cloud                       0.34.0
- google-cloud-core                  1.1.0
- google-cloud-firestore             1.6.1
- google-cloud-storage               1.24.1
- google-resumable-media             0.5.0
- googleapis-common-protos           1.6.0

Comment: It appears support for this was added [fairly recently](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/pull/9541), but if you for sure have `google-cloud-firestore==1.6.1` ISTM it should have that update, but you might want to double-check that it's actually there and that you're using the version of the package you think you're using.

Comment: @Iguananaut I quickly looked at the changelog, and it seems `IN` was added in 1.6.0. I'm not sure why it's not working for Randolfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a new virtual environment with the same packages and problem solved, before this I tried update an existing virtual environment without success.

Packages in the new virtual environment:

- google-api-core          1.15.0
- google-api-python-client 1.7.11
- google-auth              1.10.0
- google-auth-httplib2     0.0.3
- google-cloud-core        1.1.0
- google-cloud-firestore   1.6.1
- google-cloud-pubsub      1.1.0    google-cloud-storage     1.24.1
- google-cloud-tasks       1.3.0
- google-resumable-media   0.5.0
- googleapis-common-protos 1.6.0

Notice that they are the same before. Nevertheless it worked.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: It's possible sometimes, if your environment is a little messed up, to have an old version of a package, but with the incorrect metadata installed (e.g. if the package was somehow reinstalled without first being properly uninstalled). When in doubt, instead of relying on the metadata check the code of the package itself